# Read Teams channels using Graph API as a b2b (guest) user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Using the following Graph API endpoint, as a guest user I am unable to see which teams I am a part of.

```
GET /v1.0/me/joinedTeams HTTP/1.1
```

I receive this response from the API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "User Login. Teams is disabled for your tenant.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-02T06:38:56",
      "request-id": "d632e493-7ffb-4260-878f-4ac931f0936b"
    }
  }
}
```

The organization for the user in question does have Teams enabled, and I am able to access Teams externally through the app.

I have checked the JWT associated with the Graph API request, and tenant ID or `tid` matches the organization ID where I am a guest.

I have a solution working for a non-guest account (an account that belongs to the tenant).

Is what I am trying to achieve possible using the current version Graph API? Am I missing something?

Comment: As per the error message "User Login. Teams is disabled for your tenant."". You will have two directories tied to your Azure Portal email. If you log into Azure portal, go to top right and drop down your identity, you'll see a Switch Directory choice. If you switch, you should see a directory that has Microsoft Teams license. That's the directory that you have to add your MS Teams app - then the tokens you get for it should be valid.

Comment: Try to use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to call the API to see, remember to log in as guest user.

Comment: @CarlZhao The same result with Postman and graph explorer

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Internal users of the both tenants are using Teams fine, the account I'm testing is able to use Teams App successfully, only API doesn't work. Tenant Id I use is matching the tenant where the account is a guest and I can see it in my JWT auth tocken

Comment: Which license are you currently using? When you use the graphics API (especially for teams), the user should have an E3 to E5 license.

Comment: The user has E3 license, and again, Teams App works fine and user is able to use it

Comment: @YesAlex, Can you confirm if You have **Guest users permissions are limited:** option is selected to **No**, under Azure Active Directory > Users > User settings > External users > Manage external collaboration settings.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Nice idea! It was set to **YES**, I changed it to **NO** and retested after 3 hours with new JWT token and clear caches, but getting the same **error**. And the function for getting channels from a team, however I am able to get messages from a channel :) So problem is not solved yet :(